# How to choose Python Intrepreter version among installed?

Tags: python

both versions of python interpreter are installed on my pc but when I need to call `pip` on command line, it's downloading libraries for 3.7 and **don't really know how can I code on Python 3.6.**

Need to load a library from MATLAB (matlab.engine library) to run a Simulink model on Python. it's impossible to install for Python 3.7. All that is why I try to work on Python 3.6.

by the way, I am coding on Notepad++ as editor.

---

**Problem solved;
Although they both are on path,command line always has worked for 3.7. I changed name of 3.6 interpreter as python3.exe and call 'python3' it worked very well !**

Comment: What happens when you try to run `pip3.6`?

Comment: what os do you use?

Comment: pip3 install simulink=x.xx.xxx,   does it work?

Comment: actually i am not calling `pip` to install matlab.engine. that library comes with MATLAB files and i am following this way; `cd "matlabroot\extern\engines\python"
python setup.py install` and it says kinda 'doesn't support python 3.7' .

Comment: Assuming you're on Windows, it depends on what is installed and how your (system) environment variable `path` is configured. If you call `python` or `pip` in a terminal (`cmd`, `ps` etc.), Windows will select the interpreter that comes first in your `path`.

Comment: On my machine, `py -0` lists the python versions I have. E.g., `py -3.8-32` gives me the 32-bit version of python 3.8.